# What's the difference between a CoreAnimation Layer Backed View and a Layer Hosting View?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-animation

What is the difference between a Layer Backed View and a Layer Hosting View in Core Animation?

What are the steps to setting up each and when is it appropriate to use either type?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A layer backed view contains Cocoa or Cocoa Touch UI controls and can be animated using the animator proxy. Layer backed views allow you to animate your UI and help to reduce the overhead of drawing by caching the views contents on a core animation layer. Create a Layer backed view by setting the wants layer property:

```
NSView *layerBacked = [NSView new];
[layerBacked setWantsLayer:YES];
```

A layer hosting view provides a layer for direct manipulation hosted by an NSView or UIView. Layer hosting views can be used for embedding core animation drawing and animation anywhere you can put an NSView:

```
NSView *layerHosting = [NSView new];
[layerHosting setLayer:[[CALayer new] autorelease]];
[layerHosting setWantsLayer:YES];
```

Comment: Also note that in Cocoa Touch all UIView's are layer backed by default

Comment: You missed "[layerHosting setWantsLayer:YES];". Apple clearly says, that you must call this also for layer hosting views, however, only after setting a layer. See NSView documentation. I fixed your answer accordingly.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/299905-nsview-calayer-setneedsdisplay.html) and [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/304625-understanding-layer-backed-views.html) discussionsvery helful.

Comment: What are the benefits of one method vs. the other?  They both, in essence, seem to associaste a CALayer with an NSView, but...?

Comment: @alexgray: A "layer backed NSView" can have subviews; it is a normal view after all, it just uses a layer as "pixel backing storage", instead of the kind of storage views otherwise use; but the backing layer of a NSView cannot have sublayers (there is no support for "layer hierarchies"). A "layer hosting" view cannot have subviews, its sole purpose is to "host a layer", yet the layer it hosts can have sublayers and a very complex layer-tree-hierarchy. Does that makes any sense to you?