# CALayer flickers when drawing a path

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

I am using a `CALayer` to display a path via `drawLayer:inContext` delegate method, which resides in the view controller of the view that the layer belongs to. Each time the user moves their finger on the screen the path is updated and the layer is redrawn. However, the drawing doesn't keep up with the touches: there is always a slight lag in displaying the last two points of the path. It also flickers, but only while displaying the last two-three points again. If I just do the drawing in the view's `drawRect`, it works fine and the drawing is definitely fast enough.

Does anyone know why it behaves like this? I suspect it is something to do with the layer buffering, but I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Comment: OS X, right? It's possible you are running into implicit property animations which are turned on by default in OS X. You could try `[ CATransaction begin ]; [ CATransaction setValue:@YES forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions ]; ... draw ...; [ CATransaction commit ];`

Answer (score 1):

`[UIView new]` is simply shorthand for `[[UIView alloc] init]`.

Answer (score 1):

Give the following before `setNeedsDisplay` method::

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:someDelay] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

[aLayer setNeedsDisplay];                    
[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck using a [layer hosting view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351503/whats-the-difference-between-a-coreanimation-layer-backed-view-and-a-layer-hosti).

Instead of using the drawLayer:inContext: method, setup the view you want and add a CALayer to it:

```
UIView *layerHosting = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[layerHosting setLayer:[[CALayer new] autorelease]];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've never seen `[UIView new]` before (but it really exists according to Apple's docs). I recommend using `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]` and `[CALayer layer]`, however, because that's the way they are meant to be used.

Comment: You should use `-initWithFrame:` to be safe, since that's the designated initializer. Probably harmless though. (You can just pass `CGRectZero`.)

Comment: Also, you can use `+[ CALayer layer ]` (which works for ARC and non-ARC) vs `[[CALayer new ] autorelease]`...

Comment: finally, the docs say to call `-setWantsLayer:YES` after setting your layer to get a layer hosting view.

Comment: [NSObject new] is defined on the base class and I use it in place of the [[NSObject alloc] init] pattern for brevity. As pointed out above it's not a good idea to do this to a view since it needs to be initWithRect: before it can be brought onscreen.