# How to fix focus ring's highlight being clipped when using CALayer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, nstextfield

The window's contentView has NSTextFields. (MacOS)

i'm using interface builder to setup the window and its features, so nothing in awakeFromNib except this:

```
[[self.window contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];
CALayer *layer = [[self.window contentView] layer];
CGColorRef lightGray = CGColorCreateGenericGray(0.93, 1.0);
[layer setBackgroundColor:lightGray];
CGColorRelease(lightGray);
```

However, the textField's focus ring is not visible outside the bounds of the textField.

With layer:
[image]

Without a layer:
[image]

i'm thinking that this display issue is something bigger than this, but i can't find an example of this problem, (and solution).

anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a long-known issue -- there's a [mention](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/220092-animating-view-transitions-with-core-animation-problems-with-basiccocoaanimations-sample.html#220170) on the Cocoa-dev mailing list back in 2008. The focus ring actually gets drawn *outside* its view's frame. NSView drawing is allowed to do this, but it doesn't work with CALayers. Despite a hopeful note in the [Leopard AppKit release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html#NSView) called **Views, Focus Rings, and Drawing Performance**, this has not changed.

In theory, it's possible to monkey around with the text fields' layers' frames and add some padding to allow the focus ring to show fully. However, I've just tried this and it seems that, for NSTextField at least, it won't draw neatly inside a changed frame. Give it a try, though -- I didn't fuss with it for too long. (The focus ring extends 4 pixels out from the frame in each direction.)

Just as a note, you are technically breaking the layer-backed rules, which may be part of why you are having difficulty. From [`NSView setWantsLayer:` docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-SW61):

> **When using layer-backed views you should never interact directly with the layer.**

You're using a layer-backed view and changing its background. You could get around this by making your own layer, but:

> **When using a layer-hosting view you should not rely on the view for drawing, nor should you add subviews to the layer-hosting view.**

which rules out putting text fields in the view.

(Refer to this SO question if needed: [Difference Between Layer-Backed and Layer-Hosting Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351503/whats-the-difference-between-a-coreanimation-layer-backed-view-and-a-layer-hosti))

Comment: thanks josh, for your most helpful answer about the focus ring issue, and also extending my understanding of layer-backed v. layer-hosting differences. i'm going to subclass NSView to get the background treatment that i want. i did think that using a layer was an appropriate way to have a view's background customized without subclassing. thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: For the record, the focus ring issue seems to be fixed in Mavericks.  (I tested with an outline view rather than a text field, but I would guess it's the same bug.)