# custom NSView with video player is not showing (MacOS)

Tags: objective-c, macos, avplayer, nsview, avkit

I have created a custom NSView with an AVPlayer embedded and it is not showing at all

this is my header:

```
@interface VideoPlayer : NSView
- (void)loadVideo;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation VideoPlayer

AVPlayer *avPlayer;
AVPlayerLayer* playerLayer;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)rect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:rect];
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    self.hidden = NO;
    return self;
}

-(void) loadVideo {
    [avPlayer pause];
    avPlayer = nil;
    playerLayer = nil;

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://~/Documents/tests.mp4"];
    //same error with a valid url
    //NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4"];

    avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
    playerLayer.frame = self.frame;//or your desired CGRect
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    //playerLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

    [avPlayer play];
}

@end
```

And this is how I am creating the view:

```
view = [[VideoPlayer alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 500, 500)];
view.hidden = false;
[view loadVideo];
[parent_view addSubview:view];
```

I have tried multiple combinations, but the result is always the same... Nothing is being rendered on the application.

On the other hand, if I override the method drawRect in my view like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
         [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
         [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
         NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
         [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

I am getting a white rectangle where it is suppose to show my video which is expected. So I assume that I am missing something else, but most of the examples are using UIView which is not an option for me at this moment (I am working with some specific constraints)

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Update:

This finally worked for me:

```
-(void) loadVideo {

    AVPlayer *avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/Users/xxxxxxxx/Documents/xxxxxxx.mp4"]];
    AVPlayerView *playerView = [[AVPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [playerView setPlayer:avPlayer];
    [self addSubview:playerView];
    [playerView.player play];
}
```

Comment: I was using a file at ~/Documents/tests.mp4. In case that the url is invalid, shouldn't it show at least an empty player?

Comment: Tried with NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4"];

but it is still not showing anything. (stackoverflow is trimming the http part of the url)

Comment: Maybe you should `loadVideo` after `addSubView`. Check if view.window exist in the `loadVideo`. View is just a delegate. It can't do anything winout a window.

Comment: Tried that, self.window exists. Also loadVideo after addSubView did not solve the problem. The only way to make it work so far is by overriding drawRect

Comment: See [What's the difference between a CoreAnimation Layer Backed View and a Layer Hosting View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351503/whats-the-difference-between-a-coreanimation-layer-backed-view-and-a-layer-host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that you add the AVKit framework to your project.
2. There is a header in AVKit framework called AVPlayerView.h
3. Then all you need to do to see the player is to call it:

```
// **** AVPlayer ***** //
AVPlayerView *playerView = [[AVPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH - 100)];
[[window contentView] addSubview:playerView];
```

I have a programmatic demo which I could post if you are unable to get it to work.

Comment: @DiegoGomez So you replaced `AVPlayerLayer` with `AVPlayerView`, right?

Answer (score 2):

To perhaps make things a little clearer the following source code will create a basic AVPlayer for audio files.  Note that the addition of both AVKit and AVFoundation frameworks are required for AVPlayerView and AVPlayer respectively.  The code uses automatic reference counting and may be run in Terminal or used in Xcode by replacing main.m and AppDelegate and deleting the main nib in info.plist.  To run in Terminal, copy/paste code into a file named avplayer.m and use the cmdLine as shown below.  Apple docs state that it only runs on MacOS.

```
/*
To run in Terminal: clang avplayer.m -fobjc-arc -framework Cocoa -framework AVKit -framework AVFoundation -o avplayer && ./avplayer
*/

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
 NSWindow *window;
 AVPlayerView *playerView;
}
- (void) openAction;
- (void) buildMenu;
- (void) buildWindow;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void) openAction {
 NSOpenPanel *op = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
 if ( [op runModal] == NSModalResponseOK ) {
 AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[op URL]];
 [playerView setPlayer:player];
 [window setTitleWithRepresentedFilename:[[op URL]lastPathComponent]];
 }
}

- (void) buildMenu {
 NSMenu *menubar = [NSMenu new];
 NSMenuItem *menuBarItem = [NSMenuItem new] ;
 [menubar addItem:menuBarItem];
 [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
 NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new];
 NSMenuItem *quitMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];
 [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
 [menuBarItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
}

- (void) buildWindow {

#define _wndW  500
#define _wndH  400

window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH ) styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];

[window center];
[window setTitle: @"Test window"];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];

// **** AVPlayerView **** //
playerView = [[AVPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 0, 60, _wndW, _wndH - 60)];
[[window contentView] addSubview:playerView];

// **** Open Button **** //
NSButton *myBtn =[[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 30, 20, 125, 30 )];
[myBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded ];
[myBtn setTitle: @"Open audio file"];
[myBtn setAction: @selector (openAction)];
[[window contentView] addSubview: myBtn];

// **** Quit btn **** //
NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 5, 40, 40 )];
[quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
[quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
[quitBtn setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinXMargin];
[quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
[[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];
}

- (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
[self buildMenu];
[self buildWindow];
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender {
 return YES;
}

@end

int main () {
 NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
 [application setDelegate:appDelegate];
 [application run];
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just discovered that the above demo will also open an .mp4 video file.